# How can you convert a List<Pair<String,String>> to List<String> in javascript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is the Output: The data structure for the output is `Map<String, List<Pair<String, String>>>`

```
    "testdata": [
        {
            "1.0": "True"
        },
        {
            "1.1": "False"
        }
]
```

Now I need to display this data on the UI as `"testdata":["1.0","1.1","1.2"]`,
wherein here from the Pair, I want to fetch only the first elements from the Pair and put them in the structure `Map<String, List<String>>`

So how do I write that code in javascript in order to get that output?

```
this.previousData = versions.filter(v => v !== this.version).map(item => ({ text: item, value: item }))
```

How do I modify this code to get this output `"testdata":["1.0","1.1","1.2"]`?

Comment: How is this related to Java at all? Aren't you just asking how to transform some form of JSON data within Vue/JS into some other?

Comment: This JSON data is the output on postman. That is just for reference. @GhostCat

Comment: Again: your Vue JS code invokes some sort of REST interface that returns a JSON structure. It absolutely doesn't matter what kind of language is used to implement that service. The only thing that matters is that you have a Json objects containing JSON arrays containing JSON objects. Again, this has NOTHING to do with Java. Only use those tags that are RELEVANT to your question. This has nothing to do with java or lists, this is purely about processing JSON data using JavaScript. not even vue matters here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```js
// This assumes that there will be only one key in each array item, or the first key in each array item denotes the version

this.previousData = 
    versions
     .filter(v => v !== this.version)
     .map(item => Object.keys(item)[0])

// or as MikeT suggested, if you are only expecting something like this:
// [
//  { "v1": "some value 1" },
//  { "v2": "some value 2" },
//  ... in general --> { "version": "some value" }
// ]
// you may try this as well
this.previousData = 
    versions
     .filter(v => v !== this.version)
     .map(item => Object.keys(item))
     .flat()
```

Comment: drop the [0] and put a .flat() on the end and you wont have to worry about if there are multiple or no keys

Comment: Yup, thanks @MikeT. Edited my answer with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

your question isn't too clear about which element you are struggling with

so to get the data

```
async getData()
{
    const resp = await fetch("<<your url from your java service>>" )
    return await resp.json();
}
```

to format the data as you wish it to be formatted

```
formatData(json){
    return json.testdata.map((i)=>Object.entries(i).map(([k,v])=>k)).flat()
}
```

and to display in vue

```
<template>testdata:{{testdata}}</template>
<script>
...
     methods:{
        async populatedata(){
            const tmp = await getData()
            this.testdata = formatData(tmp)
        }
     }
...
</script>
```

Object.entries will convert an object into a tuple array so `{"1.0":"True","1.1":"False"}` will become `[["1.0","True"],["1.1":"False"]]` which then lets you use tuple decomposition to get the keys

you could also use Object.keys() if you have no need for the values but that wasn't clear from the context so i gave you the more flexible option